# is this sql table definition and relations is right?

Tags: sql, database-design

The problem is not big but logic comes hard sometime so the same is there. I have to save the customer data into a sql tables. the customer record looks like this in a excel shet. The contract duration lies 6 month or 12 month. every customer pay in installments after a month. every month have two records installment amount and commision amount. the excel sheet has record data like this

```
SR,
CustomerID,
Customername,
CompanyName,
relationType,
ContractStartDate,
ContractDuration,
TotalInstallment,
Comission,
paymentMode,
JanuaryInstallment,
JanuaryCommision,
...
DecemberMonthInstallment,
DecemberMonthCommision
```

for this i have define these tables in sql:
[image]

Are these tables are in correct manner? And i'm confused about the month name record do i put it in the installment table with every installment like (`firstInstallmentMonth`,`firstinstallment`,`firstinstallmentCommision`)

I'm confused, guide me seniors?

Comment: the INSTALLMENT table is not normalized correctly.  look at breaking out the groups of FIRST, SECOND, THIRD etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to normalise the Installment table to something like

```
Table INSTALMENT
    contract_id     -- FK to contract table
    date            -- used to specify month and date
    instalment      -- the instalment amount
    commission      -- the commission amount
    primary key (contract_id, date)
```

The you can go through your excel sheet and create an entry for each installment (note, this is pseudocode):

```
insert into INSTALMENT 
   (contract_id, to_date('01-01-year', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), JanuaryInstalment, JanuaryCommission)
insert into INSTALMENT 
   (contract_id, to_date('01-02-year', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), FebruaryInstalment, FebruaryCommission)
insert into INSTALMENT 
   (contract_id, to_date('01-03-year', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), MarchInstalment, MarchCommission)
```

etc.

EDIT2: added the pseudo `to_date` date format to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes this i want thanksssssssssss

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

I would put the month in the "Installment" table, because each Installment has a different month